# Puppeteer get all option's value

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, html-select

I would like to get an array all of the option's value, but I always get only the first option.

The HTML source:

```
<div class="select-wrapper control-container">
    <select name="type" id="product_finder_type" class="widget-input" data-name="type">
        <option class="placeholder">Select Vehicle Type</option>
        <option value="pc" >Passenger Car</option>
        <option value="truck" >Truck</option>
        <option value="conag" >Construction and Agriculture</option>
        <option value="bike" >Bike</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

My Code:

```
const tipusArray = await page.evaluate(() =>
    Array.from(
      document.querySelectorAll('#product_finder_type'),
      (element) =>
        element.textContent
    )
  );

console.log(tipusArray)
```

Result:

```
[ '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSelect Vehicle Type\t\t\t\t\t\t\t' ]
```

How can I collect all of the options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is in your selector:

```js
const tipusArray = await page.evaluate(() =>
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#product_finder_type option')).map(element=>element.value)
  );

console.log(tipusArray)
```

Above code will give you array of all option values

Provided all the data is static. In other words if the website is loading some data using js then you will have to wait until the website has completed all api calls then run the query.

You can accomplish the above using :

```js
await page.waitForTimeout(4000)
```

Comment: I get a typerror map is a not a function error response.

Comment: There was a slight bug

Comment: Thanks now it's working but only log the first element not the whole list : [ 'Select Vehicle Type' ]

Comment: If thats the case then data is being loaded with js you will have to wait for its completion I have edited my answer for this

Comment: `waitForTimeout` isn't a good way to wait for things in general. It's a race condition, and at best even if it does work it slows down your script more than necessary. There's a better way if OP wouldn't mind sharing the URL or showing a [mcve] that includes the dynamic JS injection if the options list isn't static.

Answer (score 1):

or another way:

```
const tipusArray = await page.$$eval(
  '#product_finder_type option', 
  els => els.map(el => el.value))
```